# Export to csv with Dash line and Text to Columns sqlcmd

Tags: sqlcmd

I am writing sqlcmd in batch file to export SQL result to a csv file. However, I encounter 2 problems in the csv file are there any ways to solve out?

(I am new to batch file and sqlcmd..)

```
sqlcmd -S Servername -d DBname -U username -P pw -i C:\test\.sql -o "C:\Test\result.csv" -W -w 2000 -s ";"
```

1. Have Dash line ----- between the header and data, how to remove the dash line?
2. The result is now consolidated into the first column for each row, can I make it separated into each column ; delimited in the result (not manually text to columns from excel...)?

Comment: https://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-csv.htm

Answer (score 0):

1- Nothing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) to remove the dashed line. You can use the option `-h -1` to avoid the headers altogether, then select the header names inside your query in a separate query on top of your query.

2- Separate the columns with comma `","` not `";"`, since CSV stands for Comma-Separated Values :)